# Memory Leak in NodeJS App Despite Low HeapDump, Need Help Analyzing and Fixing

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I've encountered a memory leak issue in my NodeJS app that's puzzling me. I've set up a Linux service to run the program and used Chrome to create HeapDump and snapshot, which indicates a relatively low memory usage of 13 MB. However, over time, the memory usage increases significantly, reaching up to 2GB.

[image]

[image]

This issue persists across different NodeJS versions, including v16, v18, and v19, suggesting it's not version-specific.

Consider the following code snippet as an example:

```
Func1(data) {
    Data2 = Buffer.alloc(X);
    data.copy(data2);
    Data2[0] = (Y << 6) | 1;
    this.socket.write(Data2);
}
```

I suspect that `Data2` is not being cleared from memory after calling Func1(data), potentially contributing to the memory leak. To mitigate this, I've tried setting Data2 to null after the write operation but without success.

Here are the libraries I'm using in my app:

- crypto
- url
- net
- events
- querystring
- fs
- tls
- superagent
- child_process
- url
- chalk

I'm seeking assistance with the following questions:

1. What could be causing the memory leak despite HeapDump showing a relatively low memory usage of 13 MB? (What are the differences between Heapdump and Service memory usage?)
2. Is there something specific I should be looking for in the code or configuration that could lead to memory buildup over time?
3. How can I ensure proper memory deallocation for `Data2` and other potential culprits in my codebase?

I appreciate any insights, suggestions, or potential solutions to help me resolve this memory leak issue. Thank you in advance for your valuable assistance!

---

**Solved**:

The problem is about buffers in NodeJS internal packages.